# How to list which paths are succesfully shared by samba

Tags: linux, ubuntu, network-shares, samba

I had some paths shared via samba from an Ubuntu host and they are no longer working for some reason.

I want to figure out whether it is the server or client which is misconfigured.

What command can I run on the host to list which paths are successfully being shared? (If something is listed in smb.conf but it is not being shared, I would like to find that out.)

Comment: You can use this command : `smbclient -L server`, this will list all available shares and services related to Samba. Shares must be configured as `browseable = yes` to be viewed.